# POST data disapearing on large file upload

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, uploading

I'm having issues with a file uploading utility in my PHP application. When sending large files (9MB+) over the form, I get a very odd behaviour: the POST data I've included in the form dissapears, including the file information.

I've already increased all PHP limits I could (time limit, max input time, post max size, memory limit and upload max filesize) and I still can't get the proper behaviour. I've tried replacing the regular HTTP forms with a Flash-based solution (SWFUpload, www.swfupload.org), still the same behaviour.

I've tried multiple files of similar sizes and its definitely not a particular file issue. I've debugged the POST vars sent using Firebug, and the correct variables are still there in the header, together with the file.

What could be going on here?

Comment: How about looking in the server logs. Try to spot any errors / warnings.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: server logs should give you an idea. Also look at the php error log, if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web servers can also be configured to limit request sizes. If you're using Apache, check out the [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive.

Comment: I gave a look on the Apache config, the LimitRequestBody directive isn't there, so I assume its on the default value (0, or no limit)

Comment: Turns out this was the problem. Except the WHM/cPanel setup I had at the time made it really difficult to truly change the LimitRequestBody directive. Raising this + post_max_size, upload max size and memory limit should solve the problem.

Comment: I have tried changing post_max_size, upload_max_size and memory limit but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I have the solution.
You must check for both `post_max_size` directive and `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']`, so if $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] surpasses post_max_size means that they are trying to upload too many data.

```
$POST_MAX_SIZE = ini_get('post_max_size');
$mul = substr($POST_MAX_SIZE, -1);
$mul = ($mul == 'M' ? 1048576 : ($mul == 'K' ? 1024 : ($mul == 'G' ? 1073741824 : 1)));
if( $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > $mul*(int)$POST_MAX_SIZE && $POST_MAX_SIZE )
{
    $error = true;
}
```

Solution taken from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#73762

Answer (score 1):

try uploading small files of 1 - 2 MB .if you still not able to post the code .

hope you have added enctype='/multipart/form-data' in form definition .

Comment: I did, and small files do work. The problem shows up on 8MB+ files.
Enctype is there.

Answer (score 0):

What server are you running on? I think some servers OS have a limit set of how large files they allow. This value can be changed.